# why this error occur-"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&xxx", and how should I fix it?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, centos, web-crawler

when I run the code in my windows OS, it's all right. but when I apply it into centos server.the following error occurs, and it's going on and on

I do some reasearch about this error,but few info can be found in Chrome. and they suggest that I should use Chrome in server.but I don't see that as a solution.

then I try to see if I over-encoding the url part.but the url just fine.

so far, I have no clue of what's going on and how to fix this.

```
        // 设置浏览器使用的本地驱动
        String firefoxDriver = Global.getConfig("firefox.driver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",firefoxDriver); // 0.24.0 从配置文件中获取配置信息

        // 设置浏览器在本地的位置  如果是默认的安装位置，则不需要设置
        // 参考：System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        String firefoxExe = Global.getConfig("firefox.execute");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefoxExe);


        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.setHeadless(true);

        // 创建驱动对象；
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        // 向指定网址发送请求
        driver.get(url);
```

I expected that after I send the request, I could get the pageSource then parse it to get what I need.
but when I run the project at Centos7 server, the follwing error comes:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_ztrd_cwh/List/list_0.htm&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E8%BF%9E%E6%8E%A5%E8%87%B3%20rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn%20%E7%9A%84%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%99%A8%E3%80%82
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: xxx
Driver info: xxx
Capabilities {xxx}
```

Comment: You sure that URL is valid?

Comment: You can try nameserver 8.8.8.8 (/etc/resolv.conf) or putting the host in your hosts file (/etc/hosts).

Comment: positive. I get correct page when I use that url in browser@pcalkins